# How to fill the text field on web-page of SharePoint?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I need to fill the text field on internal site SharePoint in my company. But when I start my code, before the filling me value next error raise:

> Run-time error: Automation Error, The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Please help

```
Sub Authority()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "OurInternalSite"
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState<>4:DoEvents:Wend

ie.document.getelementbyid("ComboBox29-input").Value = "My text"

End Sub
```

Code of button

```
<input data-is-interactable="true" id="ComboBox29-input" class="ms-ComboBox-Input css-93" type="text" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="inline" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" data-lpignore="true" value="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE opens new instance of the browser when changing security zone (eg when navigating from internet to intranet), so as a consequence you're losing your IE object. You can change security settings in IE, IIRC `Internet` and `Local intranet` must have the same level of security, or/and `enable protected mode` ticked. If that doesn't work, try enabling `websites in less privileged web content zone can navigate into this zone` in `custom level`.

Comment: Sorry, where I can enable it?

Comment: In the browser's settings: Internet options -> security -> it's the Internet and Local intranet zones that you're looking at.