# Automate VBA to load IE and enter credentials upon login screen

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, automation

I am really struggling with this and I cannot seem to get this to work. I want to do a lot of things with Automation via VBA but I am stuck on the first hurdle.

Here is my code, it should be self explanatory;

```
Sub login()

Const Url$ = "(INTERNAL INTRANET WORK SITE I CANNOT SHARE)"

Dim UserName As String, Password As String
UserName = "TEST"
Password = "Password"

Dim ie As Object
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

With ie

    .navigate Url
    .Visible = True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

    Dim oLogin As Object, oPassword As Object
    Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("username")(0)
    Set oPassword = .document.getElementsByName("password")(0)

    oLogin.Value = UserName
    oPassword.Value = Password
    .document.forms(0).Submit

End With
End Sub
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT maxLength=32 value="" name=username> </TD> 

<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT maxLength=32 type=password value="" name=password> </TD>

<TD background=/frontend/images/greenback.gif width=302><INPUT type=submit value="Login now" name=submit> </TD>
```

In theory this should work right? I am getting an error on this line:

```
Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("username")(0)
```

Error message: 
**Run-Time Error 462:
The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable**

Any Ideas? 
IE version 11.737.17763.0
Excel 2016
**Referenced Microsoft Internet Controls within VBA**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your IE settings. When you navigate between different security zones, IE opens new instance of the browser, so as a consuqence you're losing IE object. You can test it by checking `ie` object when debugging the code, use immidiate windown and type `?ie`, it will be `nothing` after `.navigate Url`

See my answer to another question, solution is exactly the same:
[click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57954707/10933223)

Comment: I have done what you asked and still the same issue. 

> must have the same level of security, 
> enable protected mode ticked. 
> enabling websites in less privileged web content zone.

Your answer makes sense though, I have a feeling that it is another setting that is off. My run-time error and the other persons are different, Do you have any ideas? 

This is driving me insane

Comment: So you run the code > IE Opens > Then wait 2 seconds > Then Run-time error '462'. Upon debug its highlighting : "Set oLogin = .document.getElementsByName("username")(0)"

Comment: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Comment: I wanted to confirm if ie object still exists when error occurs? While debugging on error, can you type `?ie` in immediate window and tell me what it returns? Also can you try `Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` instead of `Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium`?

Comment: Done that & Error : Run-Time Error 462: The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: That is when I do ?ie in Immediate window ^^

Comment: Right, can you make IE visible right after creating object and directly check it's settings, and make sure the `internet` and `local intranet` levels are the same etc? Also try to add your local website to trusted sites.

Comment: And I mean check it's settings right after making IE visible, before navigating ;) Just use F8 to go step by step

Comment: DANIEL YOU FIXED IT ! .visible <> navigating solved the problem. I did mess with the settings for IE also, but there is nothing out of the ordinary. Thank you so much!

Comment: No prob, glad I helped :) Done this way we're sure that the settings are changed on the correct browser. Btw I suggest you wait for the webpage to load differently as `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))` might not always be long enough, especially with other pages, this would be better: `While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend` but it gets tricky with javascripts loading, might want to create UDF

Answer (score 0):

not sure where could be your problem. at first i don't no what is:

```
Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
```

but when i run your code where i substitute the part above with:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

and run it with page "mail.centrum.cz" (note that "username" is on mentioned page "ego_user" and "password" is "ego_secret") then it works...

EDIT:
give a try to the Daniel comment below... 
try to use my suggestion with the "CreateObject" and add it with Daniel's part:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
```

after the "Application.Wait"

Comment: my IE is 11.0.9600.19463 and Excel2016

Comment: I was told to use InternetExplorerMedium as the DoEvents & Loop Function was breaking for me. 

By using InternetExplorerMedium I was able to fix that.

Comment: I cannot access that website due to a work policy with International websites. Is the code I provided look correct to you? 

I am not sure why the run-time error is being generated

Comment: i checked your solution again and after adding Microsoft Internet Controls reference it works for me on the mail.centrum.cz page without any changes in your code. maybe try to check again the page elements if they are really correct declared in your code.